# I can't install Fluentd (td-agent2)

Tags: curl, redhat, fluentd

I am a newbie to use fluentd.
I am trying to install td-agent2 but I had some problem.

Firstly, I tried to curl according to install manual.

`$ sudo curl -L https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-redhat-td-agent2.sh | sh`

but the result is
`curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version..`

I googled and most people said to need to upgrade curl or openssl version.

My info is below
- centos 5.8
- curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

I tried "yum update curl" but curl 7.15.5 is most latest that I can update via yum.

so I just copied and pasted source of "install-redhat-td-agent2.sh" 
and then just excuted the script.

but the result is

```
error: https://packages.treasuredata.com/GPG-KEY-td-agent: import read failed(-1).
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
```

`http://packages.treasuredata.com/2/redhat/5.4/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
 [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

`Trying other mirror.`

How can I install td-agent2 on my server successfully?
I need your help T.T

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Check these links to install - https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/install-by-rpm

https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/install-by-deb

Here you can download manually - https://www.fluentd.org/download

Comment: I already checked the link. they just said use curl..  I am wondering what is the matter on my situation.